# css of social share buttons

Tags: html, css, facebook

I've recently got my website up and running. I'm in a bit of a rush at the moment, could anyone tell me of a way of styling the divs so they are all displayed horizontally. I'v got them all in a div.

```css
#questionTitleDiv { width: 280px; height: 70px; margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; background-color: #F3F781; border-radius: 10px;}

#questionTitleDiv h2 { font-size: 18px;}

#shareButtonDiv { display: inline;}

#facebookSharer { display: inline;}

#twittertweet { display: inline;}

#google+Share { display: inline;}

#questionAnswerDiv { width: 250px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; background-color: #F3F781; border-radius: 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="questionTitleDiv">
  <h2>Question?</h2>
  <div id="shareButtonsDiv">
    <div id="facebooksharer" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.example.com/examplehtml" data-layout="button_count"></div>
    <div id="twittertweet"><a class="twitter-share-button" href="http://www.example.com/example.html" data-related="carpetinfo_com" data-size="medium" data-count="horizontal" data-counturl="http://www.example.com/example.html">Tweet</a></div>
    <div id="google+Share" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="questionAnswerDiv">
  <p>answer!!</p>
</div>
```

when they display, the facebook div is a little lower than the others. I've tried positioning them absolutely, with the containing div positioned relative so it stays in the flow of the page. But they all jumble up. Vertical align doesn't work on them. and margin-top or padding-top doesn't work either, i', kind of stuck and in a rush.

Comment: The `+` character is invalid in an HTML id

Comment: it works alright though. Any special reason

Answer (score 0):

Could a simple [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) work for you ?

```
#shareButtonsDiv div{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/su3wt0hy/

Comment: actually it was an error in code. I put #shareButtonDiv instead of #shareButtonsDiv. absolute does work. thanks and sorry for poor question.